# Can the python responder library work inside a conda environment?

Tags: python, anaconda

I'm trying to use the responder package (https://github.com/taoufik07/responder) in a conda environment. But I'm getting the following error:

```
conda create --name tmp python=3.7
conda activate tmp
conda install -c conda-forge responder
python -c "import responder;"
```

And then I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/x/opt/anaconda3/envs/dex/lib/python3.7/site-packages/responder/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .core import *
  File "/Users/x/opt/anaconda3/envs/dex/lib/python3.7/site-packages/responder/core.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .api import API
  File "/Users/x/opt/anaconda3/envs/dex/lib/python3.7/site-packages/responder/api.py", line 20, in <module>
    from . import models, status_codes
  File "/Users/x/opt/anaconda3/envs/dex/lib/python3.7/site-packages/responder/models.py", line 12, in <module>
    import graphene
  File "/Users/x/opt/anaconda3/envs/dex/lib/python3.7/site-packages/graphene/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from .types import (
  File "/Users/x/opt/anaconda3/envs/dex/lib/python3.7/site-packages/graphene/types/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .scalars import Scalar, String, ID, Int, Float, Boolean
  File "/Users/x/opt/anaconda3/envs/dex/lib/python3.7/site-packages/graphene/types/scalars.py", line 2, in <module>
    from graphql.language.ast import (BooleanValue, FloatValue, IntValue,
ImportError: cannot import name 'BooleanValue' from 'graphql.language.ast' (/Users/x/opt/anaconda3/envs/dex/lib/python3.7/site-packages/graphql/language/ast.py)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think You haven't activated the Conda environment

**MANUAL PROCESS**

**above error is not module error** that import error so in that module something is missing go to the site-packages and into that library then check the code

**REINSTALLING**

remove that library, and re-install through the **pip OR below command**, check the python version.

```
    $ pipenv install responder

    $ pipenv install -e git+https://github.com/taoufik07/responder.git#egg=responder
```

Comment: The environment is activated, see the `conda activate tmp` command. `pip install` works, I'm wondering why `conda install` does not?